# Как в Yii установить title через статический метод?

Tags: seo, php, yii

Есть ли возможность установить в Yii title через статические методы?
Напиример, как мета теги:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag($description, 'description');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag($keywords, 'keywords');
```

Answer (score 2):

Все мы, конечно, любим велосипеды. Очень приятно собрать такой велосипед и нежно-нежно гладить его между вторым и третьим колесом или по ручке переключения девяноста девяти передач. Однако злая жизнь всячески вторгается в наше личное пространство путем [сорцов](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getPageTitle-detail) (я уж молчу про автодополнение прямо в IDE). Оказывается, хитрые и злонамеренные разработчики Yii настолько захотели лишить нас нашего блаженства, что запилили целую систему, имеющую `pageTitle` прямо из коробки! Никаких `property_exists()`! Никакого собственного кода, написанного с любовью, никакой индивидуальности! Только одинаковые приложения, выходящие из бездушного конвейера мира вебдева. И такие же бездушные, антиутопичные плакаты повсюду:

> Бди, девелопер! Собирая велосипед - отнимаешь работу у честного труженика на велозаводе.

*Извините.*

##### По вопросу:

установить титл страницы

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->pageTitle = 'supertitle';
}
```

выудить титл страницы во view

```
<?php echo $this->pageTitle; ?>
```

Comment: спасибо, учту ваше замечание. Свою ошибку понял!)

Answer (score 0):

1. А зачем?
2. title чего?

Если написать в контроллере что-то типа такого?
    $this->title = "Some Title"

Оно?

Answer (score 0):

Скажу из своего опыта: в контроллере я создаю свойство

> class SomeController extends
> Controller {
>
> ```
> public $title = '';
>
> public $layout = 'main';
>
> public function actionSomeAction() {
>      $this->title = 'Title';
>      $this->layout = 'someLayout'
>      $this->render('someView');
> }
> ```
>
> }

И внутри layout'a
в теге title

> <title>
>
> <!-- В случае если есть title вывожу
> его или имя проекта, указанного в
> конфиге main -->

```
<?php echo (property_exists($this,
'title') ? $this->title :
Yii::app()->name);?>
```

> </title>